# how to install perl Inline::Python in debian

Tags: perl, debian

I tried to install perl Inline::Python module through

```
cpan Inline::Python
```

I got the below error

```
ERROR from evaluation of /root/.cpan/build/NINE-Y6sbU9/Inline-Python-0.49/Makefile.PL: Could not find Python.h in include path. make will not work at ./Makefile.PL line 66.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
```

Then I tried installing python-dev using apt-get install python-dev. I got the below:

```
python-dev : Depends: python2.6-dev (>= 2.6.6-1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

So I tried installing both python2.6 and libpython2.6. Got the below

```
python2.6 is already the newest version.
```

and

```
libpython2.6 is already the newest version.
```

What should I do now?

Comment: This seems to be more a Debian user question than a Perl question.

Comment: Is the problem getting python.h, or is the problem that the installer can't find it?

Comment: As far as I know Python.h comes with the python-dev package. When I tried to install python-dev. It didnt complain like "the package is installed" or something. I tried to locate Python.h and didnt get back any result. So I think I dont have Python.h  in my machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the package that contains library and header files. Use **apt-cache** to find the package name. Example:

```
$ apt-cache search python | grep dev
# apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

*Or the corresponding version of your Python.

Now try to install the module using **cpan** instead of apt-get:

```
# cpan Inline::Python
```

Comment: Looks like `apt-get install Inline::Python` is already using `cpan`, so this is the same as what he already tried.

Comment: I had a typo. I tried cpan Inline::Python. not apt-get updated it. Sorry my bad.